# Brief Explanation of C Supersets?

Tags: c, platform

I'm getting more and more confused in regards to C's supersets the further I venture into the programming world. There's just so many versions.. C, C++, C#, Objective-C, Objective-C++ and God knows what else.

I only know tidbits about these languages (some are object-oriented, some are procedural, C was originally developed for UNIX, C++ started as an extension and is used primarily on the Windows OS, Objective-C is primarily used on Linux and Mac OS/iOS, etc), but I'm not even sure that what I know is correct.

I would just like someone to shed some light on what I "know" - a little bit more information about which are successive versions, which platforms each are generally used on, which are the best versions to learn, etc if anyone is feeling generous. :)

**Update**
Also, I hope to eventually start native (without needs of plugins, such as the .NET framework) application development for Windows and Mac, so can anyone confirm that I would need to learn C++ for Windows and Objective-C for Mac?

Comment: how will you pick the "correct" answer?

Comment: Your understanding of C so far seems to be good, just want to add a little, C# is nothing like the rest. Its a new language included in the .Net framework of Microsoft (around 2000). Objective C is generally used for iphone and ipad app development.

Comment: D is also very C like.  See http://dlang.org/

Comment: I would not say that C++ is used primarily on Windows, nor that Objective-C is primarily used on Linux.  Most Linux applications that I've seen are written in C or C++.

Comment: @hroptatyr - The "correct" answer will be whichever answer enlightens me the best.

Comment: @jamesdlin - Hence why I said that I was unsure of my "knowledge". :L

Comment: @Ben Hooper - wikipedia will give you lots of information about those languages. We might be able to help you get a better undersanding of strengths and weaknesses. What are you really asking? What is it you want to do? What platform(s)?

Comment: Frankly, it's best to treat each as a completely different language with its own goals and philosophies; after all, nobody gets this hung-up about the relationships between Pascal, Delphi, Ada, Modula-2/3, and Oberon.  A well-written C program won't look or act much like a well-written C++ program, which won't look or act like a well-written Obj-C program, etc.  They all share some lexical and syntactical elements, yes, but that's it.  All modern programming languages are derived from some earlier language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ started life as "C with classes", in which Bjarne Stroustrup working at AT&T sought to add features like methods and inheritance to C structures in a way that requires as little support from a runtime library as possible. The classes added to "C with classes" are very heavily influenced by the Simula language. It's since grown to include a number of other features, some of the important ones being generics, lambda functions and an expressive standard type library.

Objective-C started life not too dissimilar from its current state, except that it was originally implemented as a C preprocessor. Brad Cox, at his company Stepstone, wanted to combine the power of the Smalltalk object-oriented model with the performance of C native execution. Objective-C uses a dynamic message-passing system to dispatch calls to objects, a design that's directly opposed to C++'s goal of doing everything in the compiler. Thus while objc and c++ start from the same base, the results are very different.

Both of the above language authors also published books explaining the design intention behind their respective languages. [Cox's book](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Object_oriented_programming.html?id=U8AgAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) is long out of print, but both are worth reading if you get the chance. [Stroustrup's publications list](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/books.html)

Objective-C++ relies on the fact that GCC (or LLVM) can generate code in either language, so the compiler writers allow you to use features from both in the same source file. There are some limits on what's possible at the boundary layer, and Objective-C++ is mainly used either to adapt a C++ library to an Objective-C app or to use STL or Boost data types from C++ inside an Objective-C class.

Finally, languages like C# and Java are not C supersets or C descendants at all. They use C-like syntax to provide some familiarity (and perhaps to avoid having to think about designing a *de novo* language syntax) but are different beasts that work in a very different way.

Comment: tiny point. "Objective-C ..., except that it was originally implemented as a C preprocessor." Stroustrup's early C++ was a pre-processor called cfront. So it's 'compiler' started life using the same 'architecture' as Objective-C, so maybe no need for 'except'?

Comment: @Graham Lee Very good answer! Could you just answer my updated question and that would have answered everything? ><

Comment: Mac: yes, you need to learn objc. Windows: you can use C or C++ to access the APIs. Many cross-platform app authors use a core of C++ logic that's accessed from objc++ or c++ on the respective platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the name of the language and what that was meant to imply.

`C` was first, procedural and low level non-generic (at least not type-safe) as you may know.

Then `C++` originated as `C` with classes, and templates. Later this evolved into something that sets itself apart from `C` more and more, expanding its standard library in each step. `C++` is a multi-aradigm language, meaning it has stuff for procedural, generic, functional (a little) and object-oriented programming. Don't forget about Boost as a powerful extension to the Standard library.

`Objective-C` is a C expanded with numerous runtime facilities (like messages) to ease object-oriented development. `Objective-C++` is the same extensions applied to `C++`, staying compatible as much as possible with the original language.

`C#` is something entirely different. Think of it as a hybrid between `Java` and `C++`, although that will set bad blood with users of all three languages. It has a garbage collector.

`(Objective-)C` used primarily on Linux is not entirely correct. All of KDE is `C++`, for one. `C++` primarily on Windows isn't entirely true, the OS API is all `C`. What Microsoft made of a `C++` API (MFC/ATL) is a living hell. Microsoft is pushing `C#`, along with associated .Net stuff a lot. So think of `C#` as mostly Windows, although there is ongoing effort to create a cross-platform .Net alternative (mono). Apple's Foundation APIs are `Objective-C`, but the underlying OS APIs are all still C.

"Supersets" is a wrong terminology. `C` is not a subset of `C++`. Both share a common subset. Only `Objective-C(++)` is a pure superset of `C(++)`.

As to the best versions to learn: the latest, obviously, perhaps limited to the compiler support on the various platforms you will write for.